# editing drop down options based on previous drop down options

Tags: javascript, html, dropdownbox

I have a customer survey and one of the sections asks the user to rate these things in order of importance from 1 to 5.

Convenience, 
Quality, 
Price, 
Turnaround, 
Communication,

So I have 5 drop down boxes within which I want to display the numbers 1 to 5 minus whichever numbers have already been selected.

After reading questions of a similar nature on stackoverflow and using bits of the answers to put together some code so far I have this HTML set up:

```
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <center>
                        <select name="convenience" id="convenience" onChange="populateSelect()">
                            <option></option>
                            <option <?php if($convenience == 1){echo "SELECTED";}?> value="1">1</option>
                            <option <?php if($convenience == 2){echo "SELECTED";}?> value="2">2</option>
                            <option <?php if($convenience == 3){echo "SELECTED";}?> value="3">3</option>
                            <option <?php if($convenience == 4){echo "SELECTED";}?> value="4">4</option>
                            <option <?php if($convenience == 5){echo "SELECTED";}?> value="5">5</option>
                        </select>
                        </center>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <center>
                        <select name="quality" id="quality" onChange="populateSelect()">

                        </select>
                        </center>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <center>
                        <select name="price" id="price" onChange="populateSelect()">

                        </select>
                        </center>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <center>
                        <select name="turnaround" id="turnaround" onChange="populateSelect()">

                        </select>
                        </center>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <center>
                        <select name="communication" id="communication">

                        </select>
                        </center>
                    </td>                                                                                                   
                </tr>
```

And this Javascript function:

```
            function populateSelect(){
                convenience=$('#convenience').val();
                quality=$('#quality').val();
                price=$('#price').val();
                turnaround=$('#turnaround').val();
                communication=$('#communication').val();
                $('#quality').html('');
                $('#price').html('');
                $('#turnaround').html('');
                $('#communication').html('');
                //Check convenience selection and populate quality accordingly
                if(convenience == 1){ 
                    $('#quality').append('<option>2</option>');
                    $('#quality').append('<option>3</option>');
                    $('#quality').append('<option>4</option>');
                    $('#quality').append('<option>5</option>');
                }else if(convenience == 2){
                    $('#quality').append('<option>1</option>');
                    $('#quality').append('<option>3</option>');
                    $('#quality').append('<option>4</option>');
                    $('#quality').append('<option>5</option>');
                }else if(convenience == 3){
                    $('#quality').append('<option>1</option>');
                    $('#quality').append('<option>2</option>');
                    $('#quality').append('<option>4</option>');
                    $('#quality').append('<option>5</option>');
                }else if(convenience == 4){
                    $('#quality').append('<option>1</option>');
                    $('#quality').append('<option>2</option>');
                    $('#quality').append('<option>3</option>');
                    $('#quality').append('<option>5</option>');
                }else if(convenience == 5){
                    $('#quality').append('<option>1</option>');
                    $('#quality').append('<option>2</option>');
                    $('#quality').append('<option>3</option>');
                    $('#quality').append('<option>4</option>');
                }
                //Check quality selection and populate quality accordingly
                if(quality == 1 || convenience ==1){ 
                    $('#price').append('<option>2</option>');
                    $('#price').append('<option>3</option>');
                    $('#price').append('<option>4</option>');
                    $('#price').append('<option>5</option>');
                }else if(quality == 2 || convenience ==2){
                    $('#price').append('<option>1</option>');
                    $('#price').append('<option>3</option>');
                    $('#price').append('<option>4</option>');
                    $('#price').append('<option>5</option>');
                }else if(quality == 3 || convenience ==3){
                    $('#price').append('<option>1</option>');
                    $('#price').append('<option>2</option>');
                    $('#price').append('<option>4</option>');
                    $('#price').append('<option>5</option>');
                }else if(quality == 4 || convenience ==4){
                    $('#price').append('<option>1</option>');
                    $('#price').append('<option>2</option>');
                    $('#price').append('<option>3</option>');
                    $('#price').append('<option>5</option>');
                }else if(quality == 5 || convenience ==5){
                    $('#price').append('<option>1</option>');
                    $('#price').append('<option>2</option>');
                    $('#price').append('<option>3</option>');
                    $('#price').append('<option>4</option>');
                }
                //Check price selection and populate quality accordingly
                if(price == 1 || quality == 1 || convenience == 1){ 
                    $('#turnaround').append('<option>2</option>');
                    $('#turnaround').append('<option>3</option>');
                    $('#turnaround').append('<option>4</option>');
                    $('#turnaround').append('<option>5</option>');
                }else if(price == 2 quality == 2 || convenience == 2){
                    $('#turnaround').append('<option>1</option>');
                    $('#turnaround').append('<option>3</option>');
                    $('#turnaround').append('<option>4</option>');
                    $('#turnaround').append('<option>5</option>');
                }else if(price == 3 quality == 3 || convenience == 3){
                    $('#turnaround').append('<option>1</option>');
                    $('#turnaround').append('<option>2</option>');
                    $('#turnaround').append('<option>4</option>');
                    $('#turnaround').append('<option>5</option>');
                }else if(price == 4 quality == 4 || convenience == 4){
                    $('#turnaround').append('<option>1</option>');
                    $('#turnaround').append('<option>2</option>');
                    $('#turnaround').append('<option>3</option>');
                    $('#turnaround').append('<option>5</option>');
                }else if(price == 5 quality == 5 || convenience == 5){
                    $('#turnaround').append('<option>1</option>');
                    $('#turnaround').append('<option>2</option>');
                    $('#turnaround').append('<option>3</option>');
                    $('#turnaround').append('<option>4</option>');
                }
                //Check turnaround selection and populate quality accordingly
                if(turnaround == 1 || price == 1 || quality == 1 || convenience == 1){ 
                    $('#communication').append('<option>2</option>');
                    $('#communication').append('<option>3</option>');
                    $('#communication').append('<option>4</option>');
                    $('#communication').append('<option>5</option>');
                }else if(turnaround == 2 || price == 2 || quality == 2 || convenience == 2){
                    $('#communication').append('<option>1</option>');
                    $('#communication').append('<option>3</option>');
                    $('#communication').append('<option>4</option>');
                    $('#communication').append('<option>5</option>');
                }else if(turnaround == 3 || price == 3 || quality == 3 || convenience == 3){
                    $('#communication').append('<option>1</option>');
                    $('#communication').append('<option>2</option>');
                    $('#communication').append('<option>4</option>');
                    $('#communication').append('<option>5</option>');
                }else if(turnaround == 4 || price == 4 || quality == 4 || convenience == 4){
                    $('#communication').append('<option>1</option>');
                    $('#communication').append('<option>2</option>');
                    $('#communication').append('<option>3</option>');
                    $('#communication').append('<option>5</option>');
                }else if(turnaround == 5 || price == 5 || quality == 5 || convenience == 5){
                    $('#communication').append('<option>1</option>');
                    $('#communication').append('<option>2</option>');
                    $('#communication').append('<option>3</option>');
                    $('#communication').append('<option>4</option>');
                }                                           
            }
```

But as you can guess it doesnt work. And I am stuck and can not find a solution.

Comment: @MelancialUK I am not sure. But I understand this method even though it isnt working I feel it is close. And I dont know an alternative way of doing it

Comment: Ah right thanks. So what is the solution?

Comment: I've given an answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575582/building-a-dynamic-dropdown-in-javascript/25580272#25580272